# Initializing an SDK in AppDelegate.m while using React Expo plugin?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am attempting to [initialize an SDK from a library](https://docs.sentiance.com/a-complete-integration/react-native-quick-start/initialization) which requires it to be loaded in the AppDelegate.m file.

It asks to add the following code inside the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`: method of the `AppDelegate` class.:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    SENTInitializationResult *result = [[[RNSentianceHelper alloc] init] initializeSDKWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
    return YES;
}
```

I am currently using a React Expo "managed" workflow meaning the native directories get generated so I currently do not have access to the AppDelegate.m file.

To retain the benefits of a managed workflow, I would need to [write a custom mod/plugin](https://docs.expo.dev/config-plugins/plugins-and-mods/) to inject the necessary code into the AppDelegate.m file on generation.

I originally [got the idea from this article](https://www.sitepen.com/blog/doing-more-with-expo-using-custom-native-code) where the author attempts to initialize a different SDK using the same plugin method.

Unfortunately I'm not very familiar with native code or objective-c so any help would be appreciated for how this plugin should be made.

Answer (score 0):

So you got all the pieces right, here're all of them together:

```js
const withSentiance = (config) => {
  return withAppDelegate(
    config,
    async (config) => {
      const appDelegate = config.modResults;
      
      const contents = appDelegate.contents;
      const endOfImplementationIndex = contents.indexOf('@end');
      appDelegate.contents = 
        contents.substring(0, endOfImplementationIndex) + 
        `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
        {
            SENTInitializationResult *result = [[[RNSentianceHelper alloc] init] initializeSDKWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
            return YES;
        }\n` +
        contents.substring(importIndex);

      return config;
    }
  );
};

module.exports = withSentiance
```

then use it in your app.config.json like

```js
const withSentiance = require('./path/to/plugins/withSentiance.js');

const withCustomPlugin = (config) => {
    return withPlugins(config, [
        withSentiance, // rest of your plugins
    ]);
  };
  
  const getConfig = () => {
    const config = { ...yourConfigHere};
  
    return {
      ...config,
      plugins: [withCustomPlugin],
    };
  };
  
  module.exports = getConfig;
```